# Kubernetes Parallelize multiple sample in directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I was able to get a kubernetes job up and running on AKS (uses docker hub image to process a biological sample and then upload the output to blob storage - this is done with a bash command that I provide in the args section of my yaml file). However, I have 20 samples, and would like to spin up 20 nodes so that I can process the samples in parallel (one sample per node). How do I send each sample to a different node? The "parallelism" option in a yaml file processes all of the 20 samples on each of the 20 nodes, which is not what I want.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you give an example of a Job spec, and how it doesn't work?  Have you read through https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#parallel-jobs ?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I just don't know how to utilize .spec.parallelism, and .spec.selector for my use-case. Could you give me some guidance on this? Thank you

Comment: Your description sounds like "Parallel Jobs with a _fixed completion count_", which doesn't set `.parallelism`.

Comment: @DavidMaze spec.completions is processing the samples in batches of 10 sequentially (one pod on one node), however I want to process one sample per node in a parallel manner.

Answer (score 1):

if you want each instance of the job to be on a different node, you can use daemonSet, thats exactly what it does, provisions 1 pod per worker node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd-elasticsearch
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.20
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Another way of doing that - using pod antiaffinity:

```
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: "app"
                operator: In
                values:
                - zk
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

The requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution field tells the Kubernetes Scheduler that it should never co-locate two Pods which have app label as zk in the domain defined by the topologyKey. The topologyKey kubernetes.io/hostname indicates that the domain is an individual node. Using different rules, labels, and selectors, you can extend this technique to spread your ensemble across physical, network, and power failure domains

Comment: The DaemonSet allowed me to run one pod per node (20 pods across 20 nodes), however each of the 20 pods is computing the 20 samples (essentially the 20 samples are being recomputed 20 times). How do I get only one sample to be computed per pod?

Comment: i think you should correlate pod name to sample somehow, thats the only reasonable way (at least to me)

Comment: You are right. I have to create 20 pods and then correlate each sample to one of them

Answer (score 0):

How/where the samples are stored? You could load them (or a pointer to the actual sample) into a queue like Kafka and let the application retrieve each sample once and upload it to the blob after computation. You can then even assure that if a computation fails, another pod will pick it up and restart the computation.

Comment: The samples are stored in Azure File Share, which I mounted in my yaml file. I've never heard of Kafka, but I will take a look at it. So far, I think creating individual job.yaml files with a loop seems to be my best bet unfortunately.